# IF ELSE with NULL values mysql

Tags: mysql, null, if-statement

im having problems creating a function that must return the amount of goals of a team as a home and away
First it sums all local goals, and then it sums all visitor goals, and saves into variables, but the problem is, i want to know what can i do if there is NO data, i mean, what can i do when it returns NULL, i tried with IF ELSE but still not working, here is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `vgoles`(`veq` int) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
#Routine body goes here...
DECLARE vgloc INT;
DECLARE vgvis INT;
DECLARE vgoles INT;
SELECT SUM(gloc) INTO @vgloc FROM partidos WHERE eqloc=@veq;
SELECT SUM(gvis) INTO @vgvis FROM partidos WHERE eqvis=@veq;
IF @vgloc = NULL THEN
SET @vgloc = 0;
END IF;
IF @vgvis = NULL THEN
SET @vgvis = 0;
END IF;
SET @vgoles=@vgloc+@vgvis;
RETURN @vgoles;
END
```

Thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IF @vgloc = NULL THEN` does not work as you expect because you can't check `NULL` with equality (`=`). `NULL` is a special value that is not equal to anything, not even to itself.

```
SELECT (3 = NULL)          --yields--> NULL
SELECT NOT (3 = NULL)      --yields--> NULL
SELECT (NULL = NULL)       --yields--> NULL
SELECT (NULL <> NULL)      --yields--> NULL
SELECT (NULL IS NULL)      --yields--> TRUE
```

To check for NULL value, you need: `IF @vgloc IS NULL THEN`.

But you can also use **[`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)** function for further simplicity:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(gloc),0) INTO @vgloc FROM partidos WHERE eqloc=@veq;
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(gvis),0) INTO @vgvis FROM partidos WHERE eqvis=@veq;
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much!
PD: Since is a function, i cant put an '@' on the parameter variable, that was the other problem, but now it works very good!